Setting Endorsement Primary Seed fails
I am trying to set the EPS in an EDK2 UEFI Application. I always get "Device Error".
int main(int ArgC, char *ArgV[])
{
    TPMS_AUTH_COMMAND AuthSession;
    AuthSession.sessionHandle = TPM_RH_PLATFORM;
    AuthSession.nonce.size = 20;
    const char *ExampleNonce = "12345678901234567890";
    CopyMem(AuthSession.nonce.buffer, ExampleNonce, AuthSession.nonce.size);
    AuthSession.hmac.size = 32;
    const char *ExampleHMAC = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
    CopyMem(AuthSession.hmac.buffer, ExampleHMAC, AuthSession.hmac.size);

    EFI_STATUS Status = Tpm2ChangeEPS(TPM_RH_PLATFORM, &AuthSession);

    Print(Ew("%r\n"), Status);

    return 0;
}

I just used some example values to test it, but no matter what I try, it always fails.

Fails how? And how are you building this? main(), ArgC and *ArgV aren't UEFI concepts.

I just get "Device Error", that's all. The "main(int ArgC, char *ArgV[])" is libc for EDK2 (https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-libc). I use EDK2's Print() function for printing the error code as it supports %r which libc's printf() doesn't.

How are you building this? main(), ArgC and *ArgV aren't UEFI concepts.

"Device Error" is also not a UEFI concept (although EFI_DEVICE_ERROR is). Please don't use short-hand.

ChangeEPS is an optional command... are you sure your TPM supports it? Run tpm2_getcap commands to view the list of supported commands.
